# Trying to add results to an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 matrixes and I want to safe the euclidean distance of each row in an array so afterwards I can work with the data (knn Kneighbours, I use a temporal named K so I can create later a matrix of that array (2 columns x n rows, each row will contain the distance from position n of the array, in this case, k is that n).

```
import numpy as np

v1=np.matrix('1,2;3,4')
v2=np.matrix('5,6;7,8')

k=0

for i in v1:

    distancias.append(k)=np.linalg.norm(v2-v1[k,:])
    print(distancias[k])
    k=k+1
```

It gives me an error:

```
File "<ipython-input-44-4d3546d9ade5>", line 10
    distancias.append(k)=np.linalg.norm(v2-v1[k,:])
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

And I do not really know what syntax error is.

I also tried:

```
import numpy as np

v1=np.matrix('1,2;3,4')
v2=np.matrix('5,6;7,8')

k=0

for i in v1:

    valor=np.linalg.norm(v2-v1[k,:])
    distancias.append(valor)
    print(distancias[k])
    k=k+1
```

And in this case the error is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-8a48ca0267d5> in <module>()
      9 
     10     valor=np.linalg.norm(v2-v1[k,:])
---> 11     distancias.append(valor)
     12     print(distancias[k])
     13     k=k+1

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: `distancias.append(k)` is a function call. You can't assign data to a function call...

Comment: I tried  `valor=np.linalg.norm(v2-v1[k,:])
    distancias.append(valor)`
But still...

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're desired output would be?

Comment: @DanielLenz Sreeram answered, that was my desired output. The eucledian distance for each row of both matrixes, so then I can use that array in creating another matrix, and assigning per each value, a position, so I can now later the KNN neighbors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign data to a function call, which is not possible. If you want to add the data computed by `linalg.norm()` to the array `distancias` you can do like shown below.

```
import numpy as np

v1=np.matrix('1,2;3,4')
v2=np.matrix('5,6;7,8')

k=0

distancias = []

for i in v1:

    distancias.append(np.linalg.norm(v2-v1[k,:]))
    print(distancias[k])
    k=k+1

print(distancias)
```

**Output**

```
10.1980390272
6.32455532034
[10.198039027185569, 6.324555320336759]
```